# Add leading zero to PySpark time components

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, time, timestamp, leading-zero

I have this function which writes data partitioned by date and time

```py
df = df.withColumn("year", F.year(col(date_column))) \
    .withColumn("month", F.month(col(date_column))) \
    .withColumn("day", F.dayofmonth(col(date_column))) \
    .withColumn("hour", F.hour(col(date_column))) 
    
df.write.partitionBy("year","month","day","hour").mode("append").format("csv").save(destination)
```

The output gets written to `month=9` how can I make it be like `month=09` same goes for hours, e.g. `hour=04`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```py
.withColumn("month", F.date_format(col(date_column), "MM")))
```

and

```py
.withColumn("hour", F.date_format(col(date_column), "HH"))
```